# Link two factories - Laravel Relationships

Tags: php, laravel

so my issue is to create the order items table, we need the order ID first from the ORDER table. However, to get the total_price in the ORDER table, we need the order items table.

As you can see, both of these tables need to be active/created at the same time in order for data to be filled into them both.

How would I go about doing this?

Order Factory:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\OrderItem;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\Order>
 */
class OrderFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'id' => fake()->numerify('######'),
            'user_id' => User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
            'status' => 'paid',
            'total_price' => OrderItem::where('user_id', 'user_id')->sum('unit_price'),
        ];
    }
}
```

OrderItem Factory:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\Product;
use App\Models\User;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\OrderItem>
 */
class OrderItemFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $product = Product::inRandomOrder()->first();

        return [
            'order_id' => Order::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
            'user_id' => User::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'quantity' => mt_rand(1, 10),
            'unit_price' => $product->price,
        ];

    }
}
```

**Attempt to resolve**

This works fine but I am sure there is a better way

OrderSeeder:

```
  public function run()
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++)
        {
            $order = Order::factory()->create();

            $orderItems = OrderItem::factory()->count(3)->for($order)->create();
    
            $orderTotal = 0;
            foreach ($orderItems as $orderItem)
            {
                $orderTotal = $orderTotal + ($orderItem->quantity*$orderItem->unit_price);
            }
    
            $order->total_price = $orderTotal;
            $order->save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You talk about seeders but you show factories, it's not the same thing

Comment: @Lk77 Hi, sorry - I thought seeders use factories to create data?

Comment: They can, but you can also define manual seeders that don't use Factories at all 

Comment: Have updated my post to talk about factories, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of solutions for this problem.

First, is to follow approach from doc - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories#factory-relationships

Second:
Create states for your factories, more here - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories#factory-states .

But a simple example for second approach can look like this:
OrderFactory:

```php
    public function withItems()
    {
        return $this->afterCreating(function ($attributes) {
            OrderItem::factory()->create([
                'order_id' => $attributes['id']
            ]);
        });
    }
```

You can create different states and combine it with other factories.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am completely confused on how this works exactly. So after creating an order factory, it will also create an OrderItem factory and pass in the order ID to order_id. Does this mean if we only run the orderSeeder, it should create an orderItem? I'm very confused sorry

Comment: I have updated my post with my attempt